# Find the sum of the first $50$ positive even integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Mental math -  The sum of the first $50$ positive odd integers is $50^2$. Find the sum of the first $50$ positive even integers.

Comment: Hint: each of these even integers is one bigger than one of the odd integers.

Comment: There are $50$ kids lined up, you give them $1$ candy, $3$, $5$, and so on. Total candies $50^2$. Now you give each kid one more.

Answer (score 6):

You are given that $$1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + 99 = 50^2$$ You need to compute $$2 + 4 + 6 + \cdots + 100$$
Note that
\begin{align}
2 + 4 + 6 + \cdots + 100 & = (1+1) + (3+1) + (5+1) + \cdots + (99+1)\\
& = (1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + 99) + (\underbrace{1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1}_{50 \text{ times}})\\
& = 50^2 + 50
\end{align}